# Oracle SQL - Group by with ROWNUM in Having clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get the user in the database who has the ownership over the biggest segment in the database. For this I'm trying:

```
SELECT owner, MAX(bytes) 
FROM SYS.DBA_SEGMENTS
GROUP BY owner
HAVING ROWNUM <= 1;
```

This, however, returns `"not a GROUP BY expression"`. Why can't I select the first row only? How can I write this query? Thank you!

Comment: `ROWNUM` is assigned to individual rows from the row source (the base table `DBA_SEGMENTS` in this case). `HAVING` refers to properties of groups created by `GROUP BY`, not to individual rows. You can't use `ROWNUM` in `HAVING` any more than you can use `BYTES`, or any other expression that may have different values for rows within a single group. Exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can.  In Oracle 12c+, you can do:

```
SELECT owner, MAX(bytes) 
FROM SYS.DBA_SEGMENTS
GROUP BY owner
ORDER BY MAX(bytes) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Note the `ORDER BY`.

In earlier versions you need a subquery:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT owner, MAX(bytes) 
      FROM SYS.DBA_SEGMENTS
      GROUP BY owner
      ORDER BY MAX(bytes) DESC
     ) o
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, the earlier version works. Do you know why `HAVING ROWNUM <= 1;` is not working?

Comment: I've only ever used `rownum` in `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses.  It is a pseudo-column, managed by Oracle itself, so it is not surprising that the semantics are a little weird.  The documentation doesn't mention the `having` clause:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm.

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions, you can also use (just one pass over the data):

```
select max(owner) keep (dense_rank last order by bytes nulls first) as owner,
       max(bytes) as bytes
from   sys.dba_segments;
```